# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object in chained view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Having a small problem with retrieving a new object on my view.  I keep getting the error 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

The field I am trying to display 'oil_gas_skillsgap' is a valid field and when I do a simple return it spits out...

[{"oil_gas_job_id":"4","industry_job_id":"43","oil_gas_skillsgap":"test text here"}]

CONTROLLER

```
public function showjob($slug)
{
    $job = OilGasJob::where("slug", "=", $slug)->first();

    if (is_null($job))
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {

        $jobId = $job->id;
        $roleId = Session::get('industryrole');

        $skills = DB::table('industry_job_oil_gas_job')
            ->where('oil_gas_job_id', '=', $jobId)
            ->where('industry_job_id', '=', $roleId)
            ->get();

        return View::make('job')
            ->with('job', $job)
            ->with('skills', $skills);
    }

}
```

VIEW

```
{{ $job->job_title}}
{{ $skills->oil_gas_skillsgap  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$skills` is probably an `array`, not an `object`, even if the query has only one result.

If you know for a fact that your query will return one result, use `first()` and you'll get it as an object directly.

```
$skills = DB::table('industry_job_oil_gas_job')
            ->where('oil_gas_job_id', '=', $jobId)
            ->where('industry_job_id', '=', $roleId)
            ->first();
```

Otherwise, remember the following: when using the `DB` class for queries, Laravel will always return an `array`. If you use an `Eloquent` model, it will return an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object. In both cases that is true even if no row is found (the `array` or `Collection` will be empty). The `first()` method, on the other hand, will either return an `object` (`stdClass` when using DB, or a model when using `Eloquent`) or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

@user3189734,

job_title is not a part of $job collection, that is why it is throwing 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: I thought by defining skills in my return view, this would display independantly.

Comment: @user3189734, to which model is job_title a part of, pass it to the view and in the view reference it through that specific variable. In this case i am not sure if its a part of $jobs or $skills

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is spitting out an array. This has helped me get some clarity and find a solution.